# CXF JAXB XSD issue

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, xsd, cxf

I have a web service which receives a user defined datatype, consisting of various fields one of them of the data type  Percentage which i defined as

```
 <xsd:simpleType name="Percentage">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Below is a warning that I am getting, any ideas where I go wrong? I test the web service from SOAP UI, so I assume that is nothing to do with how I consume my services,  to add : I have a SOAP web services code first , CXF, for the datatype I created XSD and then generated classes , using xjc. Perhaps I need to put something in the annotation on Java classes to explicitly set namespaces ?

```
 WARN  [EndpointReferenceUtils]: SAXException for newSchema()
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'ns0:Percentage'. It was detected that 'ns0:Percentage' is in namespace 'http://www.xyz.ie/cb/projections/converter/model/common', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/_dev_env_/CBProjectionsWebService/trunk/cb-projections-jetty/schema3.xsd'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'ns0:Percentage' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:///C:/_dev_env_/CBProjectionsWebService/trunk/cb-projections-jetty/schema3.xsd'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:2541)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:2528)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1387)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeTraverser.traverseNamedAttr(XSDAttributeTraverser.java:291)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDAttributeTraverser.java:101)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:610)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1059)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:279)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:133)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:356)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDElementTraverser.java:179)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(XSDHandler.java:2049)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:582)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:519)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:485)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:210)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.EndpointReferenceUtils.createSchema(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:698)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.EndpointReferenceUtils.getSchema(EndpointReferenceUtils.java:743)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.setDataReaderValidation(AbstractInDatabindingInterceptor.java:120)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Downvoting; question is trivial and easily answered by reading the error message quoted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**(Long form of the answer:)**

You don't show the relevant code (your question would be better if it did), but at a guess, your Percentage type is referred to in another schema document, for example the one at CBProjectionsWebService/trunk/cb-projections-jetty/schema3.xsd.

That schema document includes a namespace declaration binding some prefix (at a guess, `ns0`) to namespace `http://www.xyz.ie/cb/projections/converter/model/common`, and refers to the type using a Qname with that prefix (e.g.  `ns0:Percentage`).

Declaring the namespace prefix does not suffice, however:  XSD requires that if you refer, from a schema document with a given target namespace, to components in a different namespace, then you must import that other namespace.  So -- just as the error message says -- you need to include an import in the schema document:

```
<xsd:import namespace=
  "http://www.xyz.ie/cb/projections/converter/model/common"
/>
```

In some cases you may also want to tell the system where to find the schema document for that namespace:

```
<xsd:import namespace=
  "http://www.xyz.ie/cb/projections/converter/model/common"
  schemaLocation="..."
/>
```

In general, it's a good idea and conduces to interoperability among schema processors if you restrict actual locations to the invocation of the validator, or to a single driver file, but many people live happy and productive lives while ignoring this rule, so make up your own mind on that.

**(Short form of the answer:)**

Read the error message.

Comment: Percentage is in another schema, but not called CBProjectionsWebService/trunk/cb-projections-jetty/schema3.xsd.

Comment: Your comment would be to the point, if I had speculated that Percentage was declared in schema3.xsd; since I didn't, I can only conclude that you have read my answer with the same care you read the original error message.  If you want to solve the problem, read and understand the error message.  If you want to comment usefully on an answer, read and understand the answer.